# Disable openwith during execution of a mu4e function

Tags: emacs, elisp

Hi I'm using `openwith` to open `pdf` files in `okular`, the relevant lines are

```
(require 'openwith) ;open files with external program                                                                                                                                                                            

(setq openwith-associations '(("\\.pdf\\'" "okular" (file)))) ;use okular for pdf                                                                                                                                                
(openwith-mode t)
```

When I want to send out a message with `mu4e` though if there is attached a `pdf`, instead of completing the function `message-send-and-exit`, the `pdf` opens in `okular` and the message is never sent.

I was thinking of adding a hook the like

```
(add-hook 'message-send-and-exit (openwith-mode nil))
```

but I'm not a `lisp` expert and this doesn't solve the problem, probably I'm doing something wrong, anyone can give me a hint?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. Still what I'm trying to achieve is: disable `openwith` when calling the function `message-send-and-exit`. Maybe a `hook` is the wrong way!

Comment: The problem is in openwith.  Report it to its author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Openwith` can interfere with attachments.  Since `mu4e` reuses `message` mode, you can do the following to avoid the clash:

```
;; prevent <openwith> from interfering with mail attachments
(require 'mm-util)
(add-to-list 'mm-inhibit-file-name-handlers 'openwith-file-handler)
```

Comment: This works great! Can you write a couple of lines so I can understand what is happening?

Comment: It's been a long time since I found that snippet, but the basic gist is that the pdf is supposed to be a mime attachment, and you need to prevent openwith from intercepting it before it can be sent.  That's what the call to `add-to-list` is doing.  FWIW: the documentation for `mm-inhibit-file-name-handlers` says that it's "a list of handlers doing (un)compression (etc) thingies."  You've just added a new thingy to the list to inhibit.